# Combine 3 tables without using join but need group by

Tags: sql

I have 3 different tables as shown below:

```
| DataEntry:                   |  | OOW:               |  | ContractExpired:   |
| +----+-----------------------|  | +----+-------------|  | +----+-------------|
| Country | valid  | invalid   |  | Country | Warranty |  | Country | Expired  |
| AU      | 1      | 2         |  | AU      | 1        |  | AU      | 1        |
| CN      | 22     | 3         |  | CN      | 1        |  | CN      | 1        |
| JP      | 1      | 1         |  | +----+-------------|  | +----+-------------|
| KR      | 1      | 1         |
| SG      | 1      | 1         |
| +----+-----------------------|
```

The query i written out like this:

```
SELECT Country,
(SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN CallType = 'valid' THEN 1 ELSE Null END) AS [valid] FROM DataEntry AS DataEntry_1) AS [valid],
(SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN CallType = 'Invalid' THEN 1 ELSE Null END) AS [Invalid] FROM DataEntry AS DataEntry_2) AS [Invalid],
(SELECT COUNT(CallType) AS [Warranty] FROM OOW) AS [Warranty],
(SELECT COUNT(CallType) AS [Expired] FROM ContractExpired) AS [Expired]
```

The result return shown as below:

```
| valid | invalid | warranty | Expired |
| 26    | 8       | 2        | 2       |
```

I wanted to make some changes for it by grouping into country:
(SAMPLE)

```
| Country | valid | invalid | warranty | Expired |
| AU      | 1     | 2       | 1        | 1       |
| CN      | 22    | 3       | 1        | 1       |
| JP      | 1     | 1       | null     | null    |
| KR      | 1     | 1       | null     | null    |
| SG      | 1     | 1       | null     | null    |
```

I tried the group by but the query returning wrong result:

```
SELECT Country,
(SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN CallType = 'valid' THEN 1 ELSE Null END) AS [valid] FROM DataEntry AS DataEntry_1) AS [valid],
(SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN CallType = 'Invalid' THEN 1 ELSE Null END) AS [Invalid] FROM DataEntry AS DataEntry_2) AS [Invalid],
(SELECT COUNT(CallType) AS [Warranty] FROM OOW) AS [Warranty],
(SELECT COUNT(CallType) AS [Expired] FROM ContractExpired) AS [Expired]
FROM DataEntry AS DataEntry_3
Group by Country
```

Result:

```
| Country | valid | invalid | warranty | Expired |
| AU      | 26    | 8       | 2        | 2       |
| CN      | 26    | 8       | 2        | 2       |
| JP      | 26    | 8       | 2        | 2       |
| KR      | 26    | 8       | 2        | 2       |
| SG      | 26    | 8       | 2        | 2       |
```

Please provide some guidance to solve this.

Comment: could it be because you are using SUM and COUNT? how about MERGE-ing tables?

Comment: You should create four sub_querys with group by first, then join them together, instead of use sub_querys in select clause.

Comment: @Jaugar Chang: I have tried but by doing that, the data will duplicates.

Comment: You should put on your join statement and result, then we can find out what's the problem.

Comment: Actually your SQL does not match your database structure. I'm wondering about the DataEntry table. Does it have 1 row per country with the sum of valid and invalid calltypes (as in the structure shown), or does it have multiple rows with a calltype column that tells you if the call is valid or not (as in the SQL you use)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really want to do this without JOINs, you can, and it is quite simple. You have to use SUBSELECTs, and filter them with a WHERE clause:

```
SELECT de.Country
  SUM(CASE WHEN de.CallType = 'valid'   THEN 1 ELSE Null END) AS [valid],
  SUM(CASE WHEN de.CallType = 'Invalid' THEN 1 ELSE Null END) AS [Invalid],
  (SELECT COUNT(CallType)
    FROM OOW o
    WHERE o.Country=de.Country) AS [Warranty],
  (SELECT COUNT(CallType)
    FROM ContractExpired ce
    WHERE ce.Country=de.Country) AS [Expired]
FROM DataEntry de
GROUP BY de.Country
```

There is an [SQLFiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d93ba2/1).

This SQL assumes you have the following table structure, which matches your SQL, but not the structure you gave us:

```
DataEntry(
  Country  CHAR,
  Calltype CHAR);

OOW(
  Country  CHAR,
  Calltype CHAR);

CREATE TABLE ContractExpired(
  Country  CHAR,
  Calltype CHAR);
```

Be sure to also have indexes on Country on all three tables. But this is good advice for any answer posted here, with JOINs or SUBSELECTs.

Comment: It's working as well. I didn't call on the function -> table1.country = table2.country. That's why the data didn't show null when it suppose to be. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

shouldn't your query be something like below. This may not be the exact query but will give you an idea as what to be done to get it working.

```
SELECT de.Country,
SUM(CASE WHEN de.CallType = 'valid' THEN 1 ELSE Null END) AS [valid],
SUM(CASE WHEN de.CallType = 'Invalid' THEN 1 ELSE Null END) AS [Invalid],
FROM DataEntry de
join
(
select COUNT(CallType) AS [Warranty] 
FROM OOW
group by country
) tab on de.country = tab.country
join
(
SELECT COUNT(CallType) AS [Expired] 
FROM ContractExpired
group by country
) tab1 on de.country = tab1.country
Group by de.Country
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to perform the group by in your subqueries, and then join the aggregated data together by country code using an outer join (because not all countries have entries in the OOW and ContractExpired tables.  Note that this will only show countries that have at least one valid or invalid record in the DataEntry table.

```
SELECT [countryDataEntry].Country, [countryDataEntry].[valid], [countryDataEntry].[Invalid], Warranty, Expired
from ((SELECT Country
            ,SUM(CASE WHEN CallType = 'valid' THEN 1 ELSE Null END) AS [valid]
            ,SUM(CASE WHEN CallType = 'Invalid' THEN 1 ELSE Null END) as [Invalid] 
       FROM DataEntry AS DataEntry_1 GROUP BY Country
      ) AS [countryDataEntry]
    LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT Country, COUNT(CallType) AS [Warranty] FROM OOW GROUP BY Country) AS [Warranty] ON [countryDataEntry].Country = [Warranty].Country)
    LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT Country, COUNT(CallType) AS [Expired] FROM ContractExpired GROUP BY Country) AS [Expired] ON [countryDataEntry].Country = [Expired].Country
```

Comment: To add to Rahul's answer, make sure you are using an outer join, or you won't get any records for JP, KR, or SG.

Comment: Thanks! This is the answer. I was using cross join.without calling the specific field. No wonder it won't work and repeated data.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
SELECT * FROM DataEntry DE
LEFT OUTER join OOW ON
OOW.Country = DE.Country
LEFT OUTER JOIN ContractExpired CE ON
CE.Country = DE.Country
```

the following sqlfiddle is only active for 3 days if you would like to take a look at them example with data:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/539bc/5